# Eclipse C++ OpenGL - Cant Build Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, linux-mint

I just installed `Eclipse` on my new PC (using `Mint 17.1`) and run into this error with almost every Project so far. The problem is that when I want to launch my project I get the error:

> "Launch Failed. Binary not found."

I already tried to Build the project but then I get 2 errors:

```
./src/main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnable'
make: *** [OpenGL] Fehler 1
```

Here is the console log:

```
01:49:45 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project OpenGL ****
make all 
Building target: OpenGL
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ -o "OpenGL"  ./src/main.o   -lglut -lGLU

/usr/bin/ld: ./src/main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnable'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [OpenGL] Fehler 1

01:49:45 Build Finished (took 127ms)
```

I already searched the web for solutions but I can't seem to find a solution that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error log, you haven't linked `-lGL`. Try adding it to your libraries in the Linker Settings

Comment: Yeah that was it I figured it out on my own though :/ but I do apreciate your answer :) thanks d(^-c^ d )